# У мене (є) vs я маю в певному місці/в певний час

Tags: вживання-слів

> **Це запитання також має відповідь (англійською):**
>   [Is "у мене є" equivalent to "я маю"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/is-%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%94-equivalent-to-%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8e)

У випадках ***у мене є* щось** зрозуміло, що казати правильно ***я маю* щось**. А як бути, коли ми кажемо, що щось відбувається/перебуває/міститься в певному місці чи в певний час?

Як правильно?

*У нас сьогодні свято* чи *Ми маємо сьогодні свято*?

*У мене (є) вдома батьки сьогодні* чи *Я маю вдома батьків сьогодні*?

*У мене (є) гроші* чи *Маю гроші в кишені*?

*У мене зустріч о шостій* чи *Я маю зустріч о шостій*?

Мене цікавить, де ота межа, коли треба уникати конструкції **у когось є щось**

Comment: @Follower Питання, на яке ви посилаєтесь, написано англійською. Наразі такі питання не об'єднуються в одне:  https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3/69

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-перше, я не вважаю, що слід завжди замінювати «в/у <когось> є <щось>» на «<хтось> має <щось>». Так, конструкція «в <когось> є <щось>» найімовірніше з'явилася (чи принаймні значно розповсюдилася) під вливом російської мови. Так, не варто під впливом російської мови ще більше зловживати нею, ще більше відтісняючи найпряміший спосіб вираження думки — «<хтось> має <щось>». Але, наскільки мені відомо, на даний момент обидві конструкції є нормативними.

По-друге, припустімо навіть, що ми хочемо повністю позбутися конструкції «в <когось> є <щось>». Але не кожне використання «в/у <когось>» є прикладом цієї конструкції. «Я зараз у Маринки вдома»; «я позичив гроші в Олександра»; «після особистої трагедії в Олега істотно зіпсувався характер». Впливом російської можна назвати лише надмірне застосування «<хтось/щось> є в (у) <когось>», що є частковим випадком більш загальної конструкції «<хтось/щось> <щось робить> в (у) <когось>». Але остання цілком притаманна українській мові (і відповідно її частковий випадок «<хтось/щось> є в (у) <когось>» теж є певною мірою притаманним українській мові, неприманним є лише його надмірне вживання). Тобто:

- Якщо дієсловом є «бути» («є», «був» тощо), то Ви можете задуматись, чи не варто змінити «<хтось/щось> є (був, буде) в (у)  <когось>» на «<хтось> має (мав, матиме) <когось/щось>». Це не є обов'язковим, але зловживати без потреби першою конструкцію, піддаючись впливу російських мовних особливостей, не варто.
- Якщо в конструкції «<хтось/щось> <щось робить> в (у) <когось>» вжите інше дієслово (не «бути»), то Ви з певною ймовірністю взагалі не зможете змінити це на «<хтось> має <когось/щось>» без втрати точності/лаконічності чи зловживання вже новою конструкцією:

  > У Дмитра вчора захворіла донька.
  >   Дмитро вчора… мав хвору доньку?.. мав хворобу доньки?

З Ваших прикладів:

- «У нас сьогодні свято/зустріч» = «ми маємо сьогодні свято/зустріч».
- «У мене гроші в кишені» (або: «мої гроші в кишені») — складається враження, що основна інформація — це розташування грошей, а те, що вони у Вас були — це щось очевидне. «Я маю гроші в банку» — складається враження, що Ви сповіщаєте, що маєте гроші, а де вони саме — це вже вторинне.
- «У мене батьки сьогодні [відпочивають] вдома» (або: «мої батьки сьогодні [відпочивають] вдома»). Мені здається, цей варіант Ви взагалі не зможете сказати по-іншому. Бо якщо головна інфомація — це те, що Ви маєте (живих і таких, що тримають із Вами контакт, а не залишили Вас при народженні) батьків, то зазначати при цьому, що де вони зараз — вже якось надто несуттєво.

TL;DR: (1) не саме використання конструкції «<хтось/щось> є в (у) <когось>» є невластивим українській мові, а лише нерозумне запобігання вжитку прямої конструкції «<хтось> має в (у) <когось/щось>»; (2) «<хтось/щось> є в (у) <когось>» є частковим випадком «<хтось/щось> <щось робить> в (у) <когось>», який цілком притаманний українській мові (отже і частковий випадок припустимий, хоч і не завжди оптимальний).

Comment: _Дмитрова донька захворіла._ _Мої гроші в банку_.

Comment: А щодо прикладу «У четвер у нас у країні свято "День Незалежності"»?
 Здається, звучить природніше, ніж «У четвер в нашій країні ми маємо свято "День Незалежності"»

Comment: _У четвер наша країна святкує День Незалежності_. _У четвер у своїй країні святкуємо День Незалежності._

Comment: @Follower, я мав на увазі «не зможете змінити це на „<хтось> має <когось/щось>“», а не «взагалі не зможете ні на що змінити».

Comment: До першого параграфу. Не обов'язково з російської. Багато мов тюркської та угро-фінської груп не мають дієслова *to have*. Наприклад, у турецькій є *var*, *sahip* та *olmak*, але жодне з них не перекладається дослівно як *to have*.

Answer (score 3):

Як ви вже зрозуміли, питомо й правильно: [*я маю щось*](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/).

Те саме і для запитань
— *Маю гроші в кишені?*

Порівняйте, для іншої персони
— *Маєш гроші в шухлядці?*

Аби легше запитувати з інтонацією, можна додати [питому](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%22&tbm=bks) частку [*чи*](http://sum.in.ua/s/chy)
— *Чи маю я гроші в кишені?*
— *Чи має пані гроші в шухлядці?*

Також для полегшення додається особа, зазвичай після дієслова, оскільки нам важливіша дія, а не персона.

---

Це просто **цікавий нюанс** і не є продовженням відповіді. Бо я не знаю як в инших європейських мовах, й маю сумніви щодо цього.

Дієслова *have* (англійська) та *мати* також мають схожі ролі

*— Do I have to do?

— Чи я маю зробити?*

*— Do I have something?

— Чи я маю щось?*

В польській мові майже (в більшості випадків можна пропускати особи) [те саме](https://www.google.com.ua/search?tbm=bks&q=%22czy%20mam%22), як у відповіді.

Comment: Може ви не зрозуміли, але я не мав на увазі питання. Мене цікавить саме правильність уживання за наявністю обставини місця та часу. Бо **Маю гроші в кишені** звучить природньо, але **Я маю вдома батьків сьогодні** якось уже не дуже. Я намагався навести різнопланові приклади, щоб зрозуміти ту різницю, коли варто сказати з дієсловом **мати**, аніж з **бути**

Comment: Іще згадав приклад. Коли комусь кажеш: Допоможи, **у мене** проблема. Таке вживання так само є не бажаним?

Comment: Ви без проблем можете сказати _Допоможи, [маю проблему](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%22&tbm=bks)_. А щодо _батьків_ — позбудьтесь центричності: _Сьогодні батьки у моїй хаті_ чи _Сьогодні вдома (мої) батьки_, значення _вдома_ вже означає _твоє місце проживання_. Але якщо не про свій — то вживається _у кого_ — _у нього вдома_, але це не та конструкція.